# Error in get code from bit bucket repo from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, repository, bitbucket

I am using Jenkins for automation deployment for one of my projects. And I have a Bitbucket repository for that project.

For deployment over the server I am using Jenkins. In the Jenkins configuration I have set my Bitbucket details, added my repository link by creating access token.

But unfortunately when I hit a run button to pull my code over server from branch, I am getting error:

> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://pradipsolace@bitbucket.org': No such device or address

and pulling the code fails.

Can you please help me to resolve this ?

Comment: This looks like something wrong with the credential set up. Does the access token have the necessary rights? Is the credential being referred to properly? You could also set up SSH keys with Bitbucket and use ssh instead of HTTPS to pull the code.

Comment: Share us your groovy code or the jenkins file

Comment: You should also check if the route is open between your Jenkins server and bitbucket.  You can check from your Jenkins agent if the following command manages to connect : openssl s_client -connect bitbucket.org:443